# accessing json values using .each

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, debugging

I am posting back some data from my server side code PHP to my client side using Ajax , this is how its done

```
//server side
$json='{
"payout_history":"0",
"round_shares":"1816",
"workers":
  {
    "jbo.5970":
      {
        "alive":"1",
        "hashrate":"1253"
      },
    "jbo.5970cpu":
      {
        "alive":"1",
        "hashrate":"21"
      },
    "jbo.5970-2":
      {
        "alive":"1",
        "hashrate":"1062"
      }
  }
}';
echo json_encode($json);
```

This is the JSON response i am getting based on firebug

```
"{\r\n\"payout_history\":\"0\",\r\n\"round_shares\":\"1816\",\r\n\"workers\":\r\n 
 {\r\n    \"jbo.5970\":\r\n      {\r\n        \"alive\":\"1\",\r\n        \"hashrate
\":\"1253\"\r\n      },\r\n    \"jbo.5970cpu\":\r\n      {\r\n        \"alive\":\"1
\",\r\n        \"hashrate\":\"21\"\r\n      },\r\n    \"jbo.5970-2\":\r\n
  {\r\n        \"alive\":\"1\",\r\n        \"hashrate\":\"1062\"\r\n      }\r\n  }\r\n}"
```

On the client side , i am trying to use the $.each function to iterate over each worker to get the "jbo.5970" , "alive", "hashrate" . How do i go about doing it

I tried this but nothing happen , no errors in debugger

```
    //client side
   $.ajax({    
    type: "POST",
    url: "display.php",
    data:{faculties:"arts"},            
    dataType: "json",   //expect json to be returned                
    success: function(response){                    
        $.each(response,function(i,item)
        {
            alert(response["workers"]);

        });
    }

});
```

Comment: try `$.each(response.workers,function(i,item){ alert(item);});`

Comment: i just realised i have problems posting back the values , please check this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18709880/unexpected-error-when-posting-back-json-value-using-php

Comment: ... why are you running ``json_encode`` on a string that is already JSON?

Comment: Just wondering why doesnt json_decode work since it takes a string and convert it to a json object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`response.workers` is the array, not `response`.

```
$.each(response.workers,function(i,item)
{
    console.log(item);
});
```

And you already have the json string in the server side, so you don't need to encode it.

Use `echo $json;` instead of `echo json_encode($json);`.

Comment: i have problems posting back the json values , please check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18709880/unexpected-error-when-posting-back-json-value-using-php

Comment: Just wondering why doesnt json_decode work since it takes a string and convert it to a json object