# Unexpected error when posting back json value using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am posting back some data from my server side code PHP to my client side using Ajax , this is how its done

```
//server side
$json="{
"payout_history":"0",
"round_shares":"1816",
"workers":
   {
    "jbo.5970":
      {
        "alive":"1",
        "hashrate":"1253"
      },
    "jbo.5970cpu":
      {
        "alive":"1",
        "hashrate":"21"
      },
    "jbo.5970-2":
      {
        "alive":"1",
        "hashrate":"1062"
      }
  }
}";
echo json_encode($json);
```

I am getting this error in the response page of firebug and i cant figure out whats wrong with it

```
    <br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected 'payout_history' (T_STRING) in         
<b>C:\xampp\htdocs\exercise5json\display.php</b> on line <b>38</b><br />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not nesting the quotes properly. You need to enclose your JSON string in single quotes, not double quotes:

```
$json = '{"myTag":"myData"}';
```

Or better - create the array as a PHP array and use `json_encode()` to produce the JSON for you.

Comment: @Computernerd: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8172022/can-i-call-die-after-echo-with-php, after json_encode() calling ajax to use exit or die. In the case can you call ajax.

Answer (score 2):

easier way would be to make your data as `array` and pass it to [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), like:

```
$json = array(
    "payout_history" => 0,
    "round_shares"  => 1816
    ....
);
echo json_encode($json);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code exists with the way that you are using your quotes to set the `$json` string.

Have a look at the PHP documentation about using quotes:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

```
// Outputs: Arnold once said: "I'll be back"
echo 'Arnold once said: "I\'ll be back"';
```

As @Sudhir said earlier, though, it would be better to have an array and output JSON [using the json_encode function correctly](https://www.php.net/json_encode).

```
$json = array(
    "payout_history" => 0,
    "round_shares"  => 1816
    // ....
);
header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo json_encode($json);
```